# How to download the real file that was redirected using WordPress download-monitor plugin?

Tags: android, wordpress, redirect, plugins, download

What I'm doing is using Jsoup to parse download url that is in the form of WordPress download-monitor url.
Example: http://******.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=11036 when you click this link it will open a new download-page which use the id 11036 to download the real file.

My question is how can I bypass that download-monitor plugin and get the real file url instead?

Update 1:
here is the java code use to redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(location.href);
var hasAutoDonload = false;
var address;
if(location.href.indexOf("d3") > 0){
address = "http://d3.apknew.com/download.php" + window.location.href.replace("http://apknew.com/download-page","");
}else{
address = "http://d2.apknew.com/download.php" + window.location.href.replace("http://apknew.com/download-page","");
}
var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window;
window.onload = function(){
if(!hasAutoDonload){
downloadFun();
}
}
function downloadFun(){
hasAutoDonload = true;
if(hasTouch){
window.location.href = address;
}else{
document.getElementById("downloadIframe").src = address;
}
}
function downloadFun1(){
window.open(address)
}
//http://d2.apknew.com/download.php?i=er59f9t&#038;n=QuickPic_2.0%20beta.apk&#038;d=2012-02
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.CharSequence uri = "<your_url>";
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(uri.toString());
java.net.HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
httpURLConnection.connect();
int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
Log.i("Response Code", responseCode);
String header = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
Log.i("Final URL", header);
```

Over here, the final URL is stored in `header`. Make sure you include the protocol in the URL you provide. Also, I've tested this with 301 redirects. Not sure if it will work with javascript or other redirects.

Comment: see my edit i include the javascript used for redirection. I'll try your code and report back.

Comment: I tested your code and it return the download-page url not the real file.
Example: from `http://blahblah.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=11036` to `http://blahblah.com/download-page?i=vXcYVW&d=2012-10&n=97100_1350569493_5712.apk&f=d3`

Comment: That's because the code works with 301 redirects, not javascript. It will work for URLs like URL shortners and most wordpress pages.

Comment: so getting the real file url from javascript isn't possible?

Comment: Well, you could try grabbing the source code of the page and parsing it to find the URL, but that may be overly complicated if there's more than one redirect case (as some websites redirect you to different URLs based on country etc.)

Comment: I'm thinking about implementing javascript interface, I don't mind open the redirect link in my app, it just the webview I have can't handle thank redirect javascript, because it open new window. The above javascript code, do you know how I can make my webview handle that script?

Comment: I just figured out, the javascript just change the link only, using ur redirect code I will get `http://blahblah.com/download-page?i=vXcYVW&d=2012-10&n=97100_1350569493_5712.ap‌​k&f=d3` so I will just have to change the url from `http://blahblah.com/download-page` to `http://server.blahblah.com/download.php` :D